# Locking multiple objects simultaneously

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking

In my code I have a method that handles transferring money from one account to another. Obviously, this method must make sure that only one transaction is being executed against each account at any given moment of program execution. I have implemented this check using 2 nested locks (`Account` is a DB entity aith a unique integer ID):

```
public void Transfer(Account from, Account to, decimal amount)
{
    lock(GetLockObject(from))
    {
        lock(GetLockObject(to))
        {
            DoTransfer(from, to, amount);
        }
    }
}

private static Dictionary<int, object> lockObjects = new Dictionary<int, object>();
private static GetLockObject(Accont acc)
{
    lock (lockObjects)
    {
        var lockObject = lockObjects[acc.Id];
        if (lockObject == null)
        {
            lockObject = new object();
            lockObjects[accId] = lockObject;
        }
        return lockObject;
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine but I have 2 concerns:

- The code can cause a deadlock if the method is called simultaneously with the same 2 accounts as its arguments: `Transfer(acc1, acc2, 10);` `Transfer(acc2, acc1, 10);` How do I avoid a deadlock here?
- Can the same result be achieved in a better way (in terms of performance, reliability, etc) than using nested locks?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first point: introduce some ordering of the accounts (by id e.g.), lock the one with the smaller id first, the one with the larger id second.

As for your second question, there are options. For example, if you are sure that you need locking the `to` account and if you can tolerate a small inconsistency window when `balance(from) + balance(to)` is smaller than it was when the `Transfer` method was entered (smaller by `amount`), then you might do this:

```
public void Transfer(Account from, Account to, decimal amount) {
    bool withdrawalSuccessful = false;
    lock(GetLockObject(from)) {
        withdrawalSuccessful = Withdraw(from, amount);
    }
    if (withdrawalSuccessful) {
        lock(GetLockObject(to)) {
            Deposit(to, amount)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you might get rid of locking "to" entirely: instead of representing an account balance as one number, store a collection of "deposits" and "withdrawals" (be it a plain list or records in a DB table or whatever). Then you might just add deposits to "to" without locking.

Or make it not "deposits" and "withdrawals", but just some amounts of money together with the owner information and some id. Then, to make a transfer, you:

1. lock "from"
2. check that the sum of money from the tuples belonging to `from` is `>= amount`
3. split some of its tuples, say `(id0, M, from)` where `M >= amount` (if there isn't such tuple then merge some of existing tuples first) into `[(id1, amount, from), (id2, M-amount, from)]`, and then atomically change `(id1, amount, from) -> (id1, amount, to)` (`"UPDATE money_tuples SET owner='<to>' WHERE id='<id1>'"` or just `"tuple.owner = to;"`),
4. finally unlock "from".

The difference from the previous option is that you use ("atomic") "UPDATE" or variable assignment instead of adding two objects to separate collections.